# key extractionSOQL value in apex data loader with command line

Tags: salesforce

I am using command line apex data loader. I want to extract those accounts which have last_ax_date field value greater then date specified in the somewhere on data loader machine.

```
<bean id="ExtractAXAccounts"  class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
      singleton="false">
    <property name="configOverrideMap"><map>
        <entry key="process.operation" value="extract" />
        <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite" />
        <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="select Id, Name, Last_AX_Date from  Account  where Last_AX_Date greater then 'date store in somewhere in the system'" />
    </map></property>
</bean>
```

as per the above case I want to extract accounts dynamically. so how where I have to specify date and how I can use it for "sfdc.extractionSOQL" value.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it is possible to pass in a value for only a portion of `sfdc.extractionSOQL`, but you can pass in the entire query from the script that executes DataLoader.jar. This would allow you to pass in a date value when executing from the command line. Keep in mind that this isn't possible without making a few modifications to the `process.bat` file that comes with Data Loader, so here's a solution that calls DataLoader.jar directly:

`process-conf.xml` (leaving `sfdc.extractionSOQL` out of the declaration):

```
<bean id="ExtractAXAccounts"  class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
    singleton="false">
    <property name="configOverrideMap"><map>
        <entry key="process.operation" value="extract" />
        <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite" />
    </map></property>
</bean>
```

`runDL.bat` (which passes in `sfdc.extractionSOQL` as an argument to DataLoader.jar):

```
set classpath=C:\salesforce\dataloader\lib\DataLoader.jar
set mainclass=com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner
set confdir=C:\salesforce\dataloader\conf

if [%1]==[]  goto error

call java -cp %classpath% -Dsalesforce.config.dir=%confdir% %mainclass% process.name=ExtractAXAccounts sfdc.extractionSOQL="select Id, Name, Last_AX_Date from  Account where Last_AX_Date > %1"
goto end

:error
echo Error: missing date argument (must be in 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ' format)
:end
```

You can then call `runDL 2012-01-01T00:00:00Z` from the command line to extract all records with a `Last_AX_Date`  greater than 01/01/12.

Comment: Thank youso much. My only comment is that if you use characters like = in the query it will give you problems. Check this forum for more details about it. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008ou3IAA